# HttpURLConnection in Android working intermittently

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have the following code , which works *occasionally.*  I make several connection requests, calling this code. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. What could be the problem?

my code :

```
public String fetchGoogleData()  throws IOException {
   result_str = "";
   URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?" +
      "key=XXXXXXXXXXX:v_nymgdwiky&q="+ search +"&alt=json");
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
       (conn.getInputStream())));

   String output;

   while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result_str += output;
   }

   conn.disconnect();
   return result_str;
}
```

Comment: Did any one have experience in working with google API ,via this kind of connection?

Answer (score 1):

You miss the fact that network is not stable on mobile devices. They can be offline from time to time. You also have zero error handling in that method, leading to leaked connections and ultimately memory leaks.

Comment: Even if my phone is connected via WIFI , same network as my laptop , it still working differently.

Comment: Yea, wireless connections are not stable. You should add some Failure processing to your code and check the stack traces.

Comment: Any chance you have some examples of creating a retry due to  failure of connection